# How to convert Box's "code" to "token" after user allows access

Tags: php, authentication, oauth-2.0, access-token, box-api

I'm new at this, trying to hook up Box's API v2. I successfully set up a PHP client library, which I found thanks to the link in the first paragraph on developers.box.com/auth. I've read Box's walkthrough in full more than twice along with roughly 100,000 questions and replies here in regard to the matter. My problem occurs after the user redirects to Box's authorization page, enters his credentials and clicks on "Allow." The results vary according to my redirect_uri and the url of my login page where I've put my client_id and client_secret: 1) If my redirect_uri matches my https://mysite.com/login_with_box, the user redirects to that same url, obviously, which in turn sends the user back to Box's authorization page; and 2) if my redirect_uri differs from https://mysite.com/login_with_box page, then the user successfully returns to my redirect_uri, the url of which includes the 30-second code. I know that I'm close to figuring this out but don't know how to turn the code into a token in 30 seconds or less and use it to show the user's folders, files, info or whatever else. Many thanks for your consideration. Here's where I stand:

```
// mysite.com/client.php:

// ...

case 'Box':
    $this->oauth_version = '2.0';
    $this->request_token_url = '';
    $this->dialog_url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id={CLIENT_ID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri={REDIRECT_URI}&state={STATE}';

    $this->append_state_to_redirect_uri = '';
    $this->access_token_url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token';
    $this->authorization_header = true;
    $this->url_parameters = false;
break;

// ...
```

---

```
// mysite.com/login_with_box.php:

// ...

$client->client_id = '[my_client_id]';
$client->client_secret = '[my_client_secret]';

if(($success = $client->Initialize())) {
    if(($success = $client->Process())) {
        if(strlen($client->access_token)) {
            $success = $client->CallAPI(
                'https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me', 
                'GET', array(), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $user);
        }
    }
    $success = $client->Finalize($success);
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem of course was entirely my fault. Here's how I hooked up the Box API v2 with the PHP OAuth library reccommended by Box:

1. Create an app on developers.box.com and set the required redirect_uri to something like https://mysite.com/oauth/login_with_box.php.
2. Download the PHP OAuth library at `www.phpclasses.org/package/7700-PHP-Authorize-and-access-APIs-using-OAuth.html`
3. Add something like the following case to PHP OAuth library's oauth_client.php.

   ```
   case 'Box':
       $this->oauth_version = '2.0';
       $this->request_token_url = '';
       $this->dialog_url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&state={STATE}';
       $this->append_state_to_redirect_uri = '';
       $this->access_token_url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token';
       $this->authorization_header = true;
       $this->url_parameters = false;
   break;
   ```
4. Create something like login_with_box.php and add it to PHP OAuth library. My login_with_box.php reads as follows.

   ```
   <?php  

   require('http.php');

   require('oauth_client.php');

   $client = new oauth_client_class;

   $client->server = 'Box';

   $client->redirect_uri = 'https://mysite.com/oauth/login_with_box.php';

   $client->client_id = 'xxxxxx_BOX_API_CLIENT_ID_xxxxxx';

   $client->client_secret = 'xxxxxx_BOX_API_CLIENT_SECRET_xxxxxx';

   if(strlen($client->client_id) == 0 || strlen($client->client_secret) == 0)
     die('You need an app to do that.');

   if(($success = $client->Initialize())) {

       if(($success = $client->Process())) {

           if(strlen($client->access_token)) {

           $success = $client->CallAPI(

               'https://api.box.com/2.0/folders/0',

               'GET', array('format'=>'json'), array('FailOnAccessError'=>true), $folder);

           }

       }

       $success = $client->Finalize($success);

   }

   if($client->exit)

       exit;

   if($success) { 

   ?>

   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Box OAuth client results</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php echo '<h1>You successfully logged in with Box</h1>'; echo '<pre>', HtmlSpecialChars(print_r($folder, 1)), '</pre>'; ?>

   </body>
   </html>

   <?php } else { ?>

   <!doctype html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>OAuth client error</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h1>OAuth client error</h1>
   <pre>Error: <?php echo HtmlSpecialChars($client->error); ?></pre>
   </body>
   </html>

   <?php } ?>
   ```

I hope this helps somebody.

Comment: Hi, im just Wondering (if you are still around) how would you go about adding and removing files with this method, i was able to use this method to get the connectivity but i'm unsure where to go from there :\

Comment: Hi A_Wheel_Monkey, once you've got your access token, you can include the PHP OAuth library wherever else and call the API for whatever else. The foregoing code, for example, powers my redirect uri, mysite.com/oauth/login_with_box.php. User who has given me permission to access her Box successfully returns to mysite.com/oauth/login_with_box.php, where she sees a "Success!" message and a link to mysite.com/oauth/files.php. Files.php includes the library but instead of calling the API for an access token, the request is made for whatever else, such as api.box.com/2.0/files/content.

Comment: i realised that i wasn't gathering the access token at this time so i needed to go on to send a request to the api for the access token, although, i am in the process of editing the oauth class for using the refresh token to get new access tokens (Which it doesn't handle) i am almost there so if you want to see what i have i will share (the oauth class is large so i will try to reference as best i can)

Comment: Sounds good, have you checked out $rev? Box pays freelancers?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need your redirect URL to be something different from the URL that initially sends the user through the OAuth process.

For example, you could have `https://mysite.com/login_with_box` send the user through the OAuth process, and `https://mysite.com/receive_box_oauth_response` be the URL that is redirected to after the auth process and handles the OAuth response from box.

Comment: thanks Sean, indeed, my redirect URL has plenty to do with my issue. I'll post my solution shortly.